# Trying to find the distance between 2 points

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am trying to find the distance between 2 Vectors. Currently this is the code I have.

```
if (((enemyOrigin.X - player.playerOrigin.X) * (enemyOrigin.X - player.playerOrigin.X) + (enemyOrigin.Y - player.playerOrigin.Y) * (enemyOrigin.Y - player.playerOrigin.Y)) < 80 * 80)
            isEnemyInRange = true;
```

I have A* path finding that is working perfectly inside an if statement that checks if isEnemyInRange is false. So the enemy should just stay still if it is 80 pixels away.

```
 if (!isEnemyInRange)
        {
             //A*//
        }
```

With all this the enemy doesn't stay 80 pixels away it just pathfinds to the player position like it should without everything else.

Comment: Do you ever set `isEnemyInRange` to `false`? Generally, don't do `if (...) x = true;` unless you are chaining `x` tests; do `x = (...);`. Your code says if enemy is further than 80 pixels to player, do A* - is that what you intend?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code as shown. Check your boolean logic.

Answer (score 3):

Your sample code seems correct so your issue should be elsewhere.

I like to use a function like this for this purpose:

```
bool AreInRange(float range, Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2)
{
   var dx = v1.x - v2.x;
   var dy = v1.y - v2.y;
   return dx * dx + dy * dy < range * range;
}
```

Then use this function like this:

```
if (!AreInRange(80, enemyOrigin, player.playerOrigin))
{
    //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default Vector2.Distance method to calculate the distance between two vectors.

```
Vector2.Distance(enemyOrigin, player.playerOrigin)
```

Assuming that those two variables represent the respective position as Vector2

Additional reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb196336%28v%3dxnagamestudio.10%29

Comment: I just wanted to note that `Vector2.Distance()` is much slower then the code presented in the question.  It saves a method call as well as a square root function call.